# chr( ) UTF-8 Encoding Issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have everything encoded in utf-8. All non-ascii characters work fine but problem arises when i use php's chr() function.

The line works fine (with ± character)

```
echo '<a class="page_contents_right_cat" href="/page-contents/">Top ±300</a>';
```

But it doesnt, and shows unrecognized character.

```
echo '<a class="page_contents_right_cat" href="/page-contents/">Top '. chr(241) .'300</a>';
```

How to resolve this? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML entity equivalent, which is either `&#177;` or `&plusmn;`.

Comment: I can write ± by typing ALT + 241. Then what is 177?

Comment: Its the HTML entity code, and is sequential. See [this list](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) from W3C.

Comment: Ok. Back to the question again. When i echo byte-order-mark, it works fine. echo chr(239).chr(187).chr(191); but when i echo chr(241); it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

From manual page for chr:

```
Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.
```

And from the [comments on that page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611):

```
<?php
/**
 * Return unicode char by its code
 *
 * @param int $u
 * @return char
 */
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
?>
```

You really should look at the manual before asking questions anywhere.

Comment: Its probably not working because that is extended ascii, take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#55978)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UTF-8 character code instead of 241.

For ± use code 177:
http://unicode-table.com/ru/#00B1

And convert it to multibyte.

Summary will look like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding(chr(177),'UTF-8')
```

Comment: PHP chr() is still broken for anything over 255 (that is, most of Unicode).